# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Data

Tags: vb.net, cryptography

I am having this bad data problem when I tried to open it. Any idea how to solve it? When I debug it shows that `CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()` is having a problem. See codes below.

```
Public Class Encryption
  Public Function Encrypt(ByVal plainText As String) As Byte()

    Dim utf8encoder As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim inputInBytes() As Byte = utf8encoder.GetBytes(plainText)


    Dim tdesProvider As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()

    ' The ICryptTransform interface uses the TripleDES 
    ' crypt provider along with encryption key and init vector 
    ' information 
    Dim cryptoTransform As ICryptoTransform = tdesProvider.CreateEncryptor(Me.key, Me.iv)


    Dim encryptedStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim cryptStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(encryptedStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)


    cryptStream.Write(inputInBytes, 0, inputInBytes.Length)
    cryptStream.FlushFinalBlock()
    encryptedStream.Position = 0

    Dim result(encryptedStream.Length - 1) As Byte
    encryptedStream.Read(result, 0, encryptedStream.Length)
    cryptStream.Close()
    Return result
  End Function

  Public Function Decrypt(ByVal inputInBytes() As Byte) As String 
    ' UTFEncoding is used to transform the decrypted Byte Array 
    ' information back into a string. 
    Dim utf8encoder As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding() 
    Dim tdesProvider As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()

    ' As before we must provide the encryption/decryption key along with 
    ' the init vector. 
    Dim cryptoTransform As ICryptoTransform = tdesProvider.CreateDecryptor(Me.key, Me.iv)

    ' Provide a memory stream to decrypt information into 
    Dim decryptedStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim cryptStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(decryptedStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    cryptStream.Write(inputInBytes, 0, inputInBytes.Length)
    cryptStream.FlushFinalBlock()
    decryptedStream.Position = 0

    ' Read the memory stream and convert it back into a string 
    Dim result(decryptedStream.Length - 1) As Byte
    decryptedStream.Read(result, 0, decryptedStream.Length)
    cryptStream.Close()
    Dim myutf As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
    Return myutf.GetString(result)
  End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `cryptStream.Write` you can close it and return the `MemoryStream` data

```
Public Function Encrypt(ByVal plainText As String) As Byte()

    Dim utf8encoder As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim inputInBytes() As Byte = utf8encoder.GetBytes(plainText)


    Dim tdesProvider As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()

    ' The ICryptTransform interface uses the TripleDES 
    ' crypt provider along with encryption key and init vector 
    ' information 
    Dim cryptoTransform As ICryptoTransform = tdesProvider.CreateEncryptor(Me.key, Me.iv)


    Dim encryptedStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim cryptStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(encryptedStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    cryptStream.Write(inputInBytes, 0, inputInBytes.Length)
    cryptStream.Close()
    encryptedStream.Position = 0

    Return encryptedStream.ToArray()
End Function
```

---

Update: Decrypt Method

```
Public Function Decrypt(ByVal inputInBytes() As Byte) As String 
    Dim tdesProvider As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()

    ' As before we must provide the encryption/decryption key along with 
    ' the init vector. 
    Dim cryptoTransform As ICryptoTransform = tdesProvider.CreateDecryptor(Me.key, Me.iv)

    ' Provide a memory stream to decrypt information into 
    Dim decryptedStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim cryptStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(decryptedStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    cryptStream.Write(inputInBytes, 0, inputInBytes.Length)
    cryptStream.FlushFinalBlock()

    Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedStream.ToArray)
End Function
```

Comment: how about you edit your question and add the decrypt code so I can take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Public Function Decrypt(ByVal inputInBytes() As Byte) As String
        ' UTFEncoding is used to transform the decrypted Byte Array 
        ' information back into a string. 
        Dim utf8encoder As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
        Dim tdesProvider As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()

```
    ' As before we must provide the encryption/decryption key along with 
    ' the init vector. 
    Dim cryptoTransform As ICryptoTransform = tdesProvider.CreateDecryptor(Me.key, Me.iv)

    ' Provide a memory stream to decrypt information into 
    Dim decryptedStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim cryptStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(decryptedStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    cryptStream.Write(inputInBytes, 0, inputInBytes.Length)
    cryptStream.FlushFinalBlock()
    decryptedStream.Position = 0

    ' Read the memory stream and convert it back into a string 
    Dim result(decryptedStream.Length - 1) As Byte
    decryptedStream.Read(result, 0, decryptedStream.Length)
    cryptStream.Close()
    Dim myutf As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
    Return myutf.GetString(result)
End Function
```

End Class